# Prove that there no $k$ such that : $3n^{2}+3n+7=k^{3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem :

Let $n,k$ be natural numbers

Prove that there no $k$ such that :

> $$3n^{2}+3n+7=k^{3}$$

I see this short solution from a book :

We use $\pmod{9}$

$k^{3}\equiv 0,1,8\pmod{9}$

And $3n^{2}+3n+7\equiv 4,7\pmod{9}$

$\implies $ no solution ?

But I don't understand why he chose mod $9$ and how we know that $k^{3}\equiv 0,1,8\pmod{9}$ ?

And how he know $3n^{2}+3n+7\equiv 4,7\pmod{9}$ ?
Can someone explain to me or give me another solution !

Comment: Try all values of $n$ less than $9$ and see what $n^3 \mod 9$ gives .

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit ok I understand this thanks! But why he use mod $9$

Comment: Because , $\mod 9$ works . There are no general rule as to which mod to look at . It is mostly trial and error .   Since $\mod 9$ gives us only $3$ residues , it would be helpful to look at it first .

Comment: @EllenEllen It's mostly from guessing and experience (even memorization!). For example, solve $a^2+b^4+1=6^c$ over integer. Since $s^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod{4}$, for $c>1$, the $RHS$ is divisible by four, while the $LHS$ will never be.

Comment: @Adola thanks! For nice explain

Comment: It's natural to take the module $3$ first, seeing the threes on the LHS. This gives $1\equiv k^3\pmod 3$ which implies $k\equiv1\mod 3$. Then it's clearly worth thinking about modulus $3^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for choosing 9 is that n is not divisible by 3 , let $n=3m+r$ , we can write:

$n^2=9m^2+6mr+r^2$

⇒ $$3n^2+3n+7 ≡(R=3r^2+3r+7) \ mod (9)$$

$r= 0, 1, 2$

$r=0$ ⇒ $R=7$ ⇒ $3n^2+3n+7 ≡7 \mod(9)$

$r=1$ ⇒ $R=13$ ⇒ $$3n^2+3n+7 ≡13 \mod(9)≡4 \mod(9)$$

$r=2$ ⇒ $R=7 \mod (9)$

⇒ $$3n^2+3n+7 ≡(4, 7) \mod(9)$$

$k≡(0, 1, 2, . . .8)\ mod (9)$

⇒ $K^3≡(0, 1, 8, 0, 1, 8, 0, 1, 8)\ mod (9) ≡(0, 1, 8)\ mod (9)$